# No instance of everloaded function "Getline" matches the argument list

Tags: c++

There are many variations of this question on this site but all of the answers assume the user has a good fundamental knowledge of how C++ works. As a beginner, this is not good for me.

I have a very simple subroutine attempting to print a single item from a csv file.

```
void parseCSV() 
{
    int line = 0;
    ofstream myFile("C:/Users/joe-p/Documents/Book1.csv");
    getline(myFile, line, ',');
}
```

"Getline" is tagged with an error: "No instance of everloaded function "Getline" matches the argument list"

THis is very frustrating as i know the answer is in multiple answers which i've read already, but copying the example code and just trying to cause myself just isn't working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

1. `std::getline` first argument should be an input stream. `std::ofstream` is an output stream.
2. `std::getline` takes a `std::string&` as second parameter, not an `int`.

**Solution:**

You should probably open your file as an `std::ifstream` and use either the `std::ifstream::operator>>` or `std::getline` to fill a `std::string` an then parse it to an `int`.

**Additional information:**

1. `using namespace std;` is considered a bad practice (More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)).

**Full code:**

```cpp
void parseCSV() 
{
    std::string line;
    ifstream myFile("C:/Users/joe-p/Documents/Book1.csv");
    getline(myFile, line, ',');
    int num = std::stoi(line);
    std::cout << num << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Very useful information, thank you! although, that  snippet of code on it's own doesn't print any data and i can't figure out what i have to change to make that happen. What modifications would i have to make to it to print the item in  row 1, column 1? If i get an example of that i should be able to work out how to manipulate it from there.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) works.

You need to read as strings and then convert the strings into integers.

Answer (score 2):

`ofstream myFile("C:/Users/joe-p/Documents/Book1.csv");` is an output stream, to call `getline` you need to use and *input* stream.